# Measuring average DC of pulsed analog signal

Tags: dc, measurement, voltage-measurement, pulse

I'm trying to measure average DC level of pulsed analog signal. The pulses have minimum pulse width of 10 us and amplitude of max 5 V. Pulses are somewhat gaussian shape and have very random height spectrum. See image for sample of pulses:[image: Pulses]

Less pulses is lower DC level and vice versa. Sample time of around 1s is desired. I was thinking to use some ADC with high enough sample rate so that every pulse gets ~10 samples which equals 1 MS/s. [MCP33141D-10](http://extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.mouser.fi/datasheet/2/268/microchip_technology_mchp-s-a0008495274-1-1763425.pdf) has 1 MS/s sampling and 12 bit resolution with integrated data accumulation. It can only accumulate and integrate 1024 samples so the sample time is quite low but maybe I can live with that.

I was also considering using a RC circuit to smooth the pulsed signal and then using some low frequency ADC to convert the DC to digital. Raspberry Pi is used for data acquisition so a SPI or I2C bus is desired.

Pulses are produced from two stage transimpedance amplifier where the second stage would be driving this ADC. Second stage is OPA847 which can source ~50mA, gain of 15 - 20 V/V is used in there.

I don't have too much experience with ADCs so what would be the best method for this DC measurement and conversion?

Comment: I'd filter out the AC components with a suitable RC filter (2nd or higher-order). The remaining signal will be nearly the DC component (i.e. the average).

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yea but that wont be the average DC level of the pulses, that will be the average DC level of the whole signal, which im not sure is what he wants.. I think he only wants to average the pulses and ignore the time in between the pulses.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to average out.. the entire signal, or just the pulses.. It sounds like you just want an RC filter hooked to an ADC, not too sure if you want/need anything more special than that, but its unclear what exactly you want to measure

Comment: Your 'scope photo shows a pulse base-line of about 0.5V. Is that stable? Do you want to include that base DC offset in the average too?

Comment: I have already removed the base DC offset so the baseline is now 0 V. I'm trying to average the whole signal, not just the pulses so the RC + ADC combo would probably be the best solution